# Load external images in Flash using javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

I have created a flash movie that loads external pngs using this as2 code:

```
photo1.loadMovie("flashimages/photo1.png");
```

My client wants me to use javascript so they can edit the file location.  Is this possible?

Be gentle!  I am not very familiar with javascript :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no need to use javascript, just `flashVars` will be enough in your embed code :

```
<param name="flashVars" value="imgPath=flashimages/photo1.png"/>
<embed movie="" flashVars="imgPath=flashimages/photo1.png"....></embed>
```

then in flash get the `imgPath` from the embed code :

```
photo1.loadMovie(_root.imgPath);
```

Comment: Thanks, mgraph!  I am much more of a designer than a developer, so forgive me if my questions are super rudimentary...Where does the embed code go? And why do I reference the root in loadMovie?

Comment: @Joann embed code is the one that you put in you page (html/page) to load swf file

Comment: @Joann [read this to understand  more](http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashhtmlcode.php)